# Pandas apply works as inplace true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change a new data frame's column using apply function to another df, but both data frames' columns changes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['x1','x2'],['y1','y2']],columns=['A','B'])
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | x2 |
| y1 | y2 |

```
lst = []
def getbinary(x):
    if x not in lst:
        lst.append(x)
    return lst.index(x)

modeldf = df
modeldf['A'] = df['A'].apply(getbinary)
```

modeldf and df after this code:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | x2 |
| 1 | y2 |

Comment: Use `df.copy()` instead to initialize `modeldf`

Comment: that one works, thanks!

Comment: Also note that this is a known behavior called out in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#mutating-with-user-defined-function-udf-methods) and in the Notes section of the [`Series.apply()` page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).